# Need to compare two arrays elements inside a for loop in Python 3 and getting error "The truth value of an array ..."

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, numpy-ndarray, boolean-operations

I have a numpy array in the form:

```
y_sol = 
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]]
```

and I need to translate it for a categorical string value using correlations given by a list of tuples:

```
transf_codes = [('Alert', [1., 0., 0.]),     
                ('Neutral', [0., 1., 0.]),     
                ('Urgent', [0., 0., 1.])]
```

Note that I haven't used a dictionary here to avoid a complication to search for keys having the values as the search input.

Anyhow, I've tried the following code to have the job done:

```
for i in np.arange(len(y_sol)-1): 
    for j in np.arange(3):
        if np.equal(transf_codes[j][1], y_sol[i].all()):  # <-error line 
            y_categ[i] = transf_codes[j][0]
```

and I get the error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

In the "if" line above, the more natural form >>> `transf_codes[j][1] == y_sol[i]` <<<, with or without .all() or .any(), raises the same error.

What is the righ and best approach to compare element-wise of arrays, lists, etc. in an if-statement?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing happens whenever numpy tries to cast an array as a boolean. It doesn't understand how to do so, so it throws that error.

So when you do something like `if (a == b)` with a, b being arrays, you wind up with an error.

However, `a == b` will yield a boolean array, with the element-wise comparison.
Note that for that to happen `a`, `b` have to be numpy arrays. List behaviour is different.

One way we could use the boolean array is with the np.all method which I see you used, but not in the right place. You currently do .all() on the `y_sol[i]`.

So the following code and output are the correct.

```
import numpy as np
y_sol = np.array( \
[[0., 0., 1.],
 [0., 0., 1.],
 [0., 0., 1.],
 [1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 1., 0.],
 [1., 0., 0.]])

transf_codes = [('Alert', [1., 0., 0.]),
                ('Neutral', [0., 1., 0.]),
                ('Urgent', [0., 0., 1.])]

for i in np.arange(len(y_sol)-1):
    for j in np.arange(3):
        if (transf_codes[j][1] == y_sol[i]).all():  # <-error line
            print(f'y_sol[i]={y_sol[i]}, transf_codes={transf_codes[j][0]}')
```

And this outputs:

```
y_sol[i]=[0. 0. 1.], transf_codes=Urgent
y_sol[i]=[0. 0. 1.], transf_codes=Urgent
y_sol[i]=[0. 0. 1.], transf_codes=Urgent
y_sol[i]=[1. 0. 0.], transf_codes=Alert
y_sol[i]=[0. 1. 0.], transf_codes=Neutral
```

Note that I used .all() *after* having compared the vectors.

Comment: Hi Yonatan, good day! Thank you so much for your quick response. Sorted it out completely. Just one doubt related to your comment: "Note that for that to happen a, b have to be numpy arrays. List behaviour is different". The comparison above do have a list (of tuples) and a numpy array, but the magic did work fine, as I've wished. PS: I don't have points enough to up-vote on your answer. :)

Comment: Gladly :)
About lists - it was a general remark, since when you don't invoke numpy functions at all, some of the behaviour is different, e.g: [1, 0] == [1, 0] gives one boolean = True. But if you use "np.equal", it returns [True, True]. Have a good day :)